# Dynamically create an object from an anonymous object

Tags: c#-4.0

Using a type builder I am OK with creating a type dynamically. Would it be possible to do this from an anonymous type?

I have this so far;

```
//CreateType generates a type (so that I can set it's properties once instantiated) from an //anonymous object. I am not interested in the initial value of the properties, just the Type.
 Type t = CreateType(new {Name = "Ben", Age = 23});
 var myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

Is it possible to now use Type "t" as a type argument?

My method:

```
public static void DoSomething<T>() where T : new() 
{
}
```

I would like to call this method using the dynamically created Type "t". So that I can call;

```
DoSomething<t>(); //This won't work obviously
```

Comment: Do you mean you construct an object of an anonymous type and want to get its type in order to create more of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. To use the type as a type argument, you need to use the [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method:

```
// Of course you'll use CreateType here but this is what compiles for me :)
var anonymous = new { Value = "blah", Number = 1 };
Type anonType = anonymous.GetType();

// Get generic list type
Type listType = typeof(List<>);
Type[] typeParams = new Type[] { anonType };
Type anonListType = listType.MakeGenericType(typeParams);

// Create the list
IList anonList = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(anonListType);

// create an instance of the anonymous type and add it
var t = Activator.CreateInstance(anonType, "meh", 2); // arguments depending on the constructor, the default anonymous type constructor just takes all properties in their declaration order
anonList.Add(t);
```